# Are Shumann waves on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are [Schumann resonances (SR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schumann_resonances) on topic?

Like background radiation
of the Earth (the Shumann wave) at 7.8 Hertz?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions about the physics of the Shumann resonance should be on topic. At the upper levels of our atmosphere we start to overlap with physics.se and space.se. With this being an atmospheric phenomena and linked to tropospheric phenomena (lightning and temperature) I am inclined to say questions about them belong on this site.

Based on your single question on the site I will add one caveat: While these may be on topic, pseudo science based upon them is not.